# Ethereum Solidity modifiers

Tags: solidity

I am trying to do something like this in Solidity as a modifier but it wont work.

```
modifier onlyManagement {

    require( msg.sender == management || msg.sender == owner );
    _;

}

function someFunction() public onlyManagement{
  // do something
}
```

I want to be able for the owner of the contract or the manager to have access to it.

Comment: This code is ok. Maybe the way of calling `someFunction` method is error~

Comment: The function works fine. The management is able to call it but not the owner.  If I switch the positions in the require function the owner is able to call the contract but not the manager...


For some reason the "||" operator doesnt work right.

I also tried doing 

       if ( msg.sender != management || msg.sender != owner) throw;

It doesnt work either... the OR operator doesnt seem to work right

Comment: if ( msg.sender != management && msg.sender != owner)  throw;  there is `&&` op~

Comment: I changed the compiler version to 4.11 in solidity browser and it now works...

Comment: Thank you for that Bin...  I missed that one...  As for the require... looks like the latest compiler is giving a problem so I went back to an earlier complier and it worked.

Comment: I was unable to repro this, but it seems like a pretty serious issue. What version of the compiler were you using? Can you share the smallest complete code that has this issue? Are you sure you were using the right addresses to make the calls?

I tested this code, with both 0.4.16 and 0.4.15 with no issue. https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/0ee074ceb29d7be240e8b414f632ac83/raw/bde9c3d49384a1440f90a0cd7411cc7e52e3709c/Untitled.sol

Comment: I don't recall which exact version it was... but it certainly was happening.

I changed nothing in the code... only the compiler to solve it.